# Catching and Error with an Exception

Tags: php

I am trying to throw an error if the socket fails to execute for whatever reason.

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) OR throw new main_excp(error_pack(3050, 'Failed (socket_create): ' . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) .'!', true));
```

However this does not work like so as I get an error.

If I use `OR die()` the script will exit right there, and I won't be able to process the error accordingly inside `catch{}`.

Whats the correct way to this exact this?

Comment: `throw` is a [statement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), it doesn't have a value. Accordingly, it cannot be used in expressions. Stay away from any tutorial that teaches you that `mysql_query() or die()` is error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php) says:

> socket_create() returns a socket resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error. The actual error code can be retrieved by calling
>   socket_last_error(). This error code may be passed to
>   socket_strerror() to get a textual explanation of the error.

So, you can check `$socket` for an false value (with `$socket === false`) and get the error using the functions `socket_last_error()` and `socket_sterror()`.